# How to prevent scripts from changing the terminal's window title?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, script, zsh

I'm using GNOME Terminal and zsh on Ubuntu with Awesome WM.

I need to launch a terminal window with a certain title set like "s1" and no script inside that terminal should change the title of the tab or window.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the version of gnome-terminal I have (3.2) there's an option under:

Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title and Command

"When terminal commands set their own title" with a drop down box. One of the options is "Keep initial title"

That ought to do it :)

Comment: Also, to manually set the title, you would need to go to *Terminal → Set Title*.

Comment: right - you can also set that when launching it, gnome-terminal -t s1.  I can't see a command line option for preventing it being set though.

Comment: Thank you guys so much. Now I can magnet my terminal apps to the right workspaces by setting the title of the wrapping terminal. Win!